# Opening a tab in tabpanel from external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

In image I have menu about, exhibition and awards. After clicking this menu option I want to open that tab. for eg. when I click about, profile tab will open, on clicking exhibition, recent exhibition tab will open etc. Not getting proper code to open that specific tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
```

jQuery(function ($) {

```
var open_accordion_anchor = $('#t1 a');
open_accordion_anchor.on('click', function(event){
    $('#myTab .one a').click();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#myTab').offset().top }, 1000);
});
var open_accordion_anchor = $('#t2 a');
open_accordion_anchor.on('click', function(event){
    $('#myTab .two a').click();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#myTab').offset().top }, 1000);
});
var open_accordion_anchor = $('#t3 a');
open_accordion_anchor.on('click', function(event){
    $('#myTab .three a').click();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#myTab').offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

});

I have used this and it worked for me but now I want to open it from another from page.